# Send two different emails when one form is submitted

Tags: php

What I'm basically trying to do is I want to send one email to the user, when the form is submitted, and other one to my email, so I can know everytime someone submits my form. My code is partly working, it sends "Someone submitted your form" email to my admin email it also sends it to the user, so user ends up recieving verification email and "Someone submitted form" email.

I use PHPMailer:

```
    <?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

require '../mails/vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(TRUE);

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "in-v3.mailjet.com";
$mail->Port = "587";

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = '27eb6a1159ffcf5797a2c2cf45c17337';
$mail->Password = '0da8753f2f792c794f61ba25490f5c65';

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

/* Send E-Mail to User */

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name  = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $mail->setFrom('aleksaprebiracevicorona@gmail.com', 'Spirituality & Coaching');

    $mail->addAddress($email);

    $mail->Subject = 'E-Mail Verification';

    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->Body = "
    <table style='padding: 0 20px; border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;' width='600px' align='center' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class='logo' style='text-align: center; padding: 40px 0px'>
    <img style='height: 60px; width: auto;' src='https://i.imgur.com/wZ5CPn9.png'>
    </div>
    <div style='text-align: left; color: #222 !important;'>
    <br>Welcome <b>" . $name . "</b>,
    <p style='margin-bottom: 0; color: #222;'>You have requested the verification of<b> " . $email . "</b> email address. To proceed you just need to click on verification link below. After you pass the email verification you will be able to see the <b>FULL</b> video.</p>
    <p style='margin-bottom: 35px; color: #222;'><b>Verification Link:</b> <a href='https://www.easybewussterschaffen.com/verify.php?verified=1'>Click here</a></p></div>
    <br>
    <div style='text-align: center;padding: 30px 0px; border-top: 1px solid #c9c9c9;'><img style='margin-right: 15px;' src='https://i.imgur.com/Dm6EbMf.png'> <img style='margin-right: 15px;' src='https://i.imgur.com/3Gqe82I.png'> <img src='https://i.imgur.com/6UaoHYI.png'></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
    ";

}

 /* Send E-Mail to Admin */

if ($mail->Send() == true) {

    $mail->setFrom('aleksaprebiracevicorona@gmail.com', 'Spirituality & Coaching');

    $mail->addAddress('coronafashion65@gmail.com');

    $mail->Subject = 'Someone submitted form!';

    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->Body = "
    <p>Someone submitted a form</p>
    ";

    $mail->Send();

    exit;
}

header("Location: https://www.easybewussterschaffen.com/index.php?success=1");

?>
```

How can I achive this and send two seperate emails, one to the user and another to the admin. Any help will mean a lot!

You can also try form here: https://www.easybewussterschaffen.com
You will recieve both emails.

Comment: If just notifing yourself is your goal why not add your admin mail as bcc to the first mail with `$mail->addBcc('your-admin-mail@domain.example');`?

Comment: Well I want to have different content for both emails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [`$mail->ClearAddresses()`](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_clearAddresses) method

```
/* Send E-Mail to Admin */

if ($mail->Send() == true) {

    $mail->ClearAddresses(); // Clear recipients
    $mail->setFrom('aleksaprebiracevicorona@gmail.com', 'Spirituality & Coaching');

    $mail->addAddress('coronafashion65@gmail.com');

    $mail->Subject = 'Someone submitted form!';

    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->Body = "
    <p>Someone submitted a form</p>
    ";

    $mail->Send();

    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would call `$mail = new PHPMailer(TRUE);` for each message you wish to send, and construct a new message.